# An error occurred rendering the PivotTable results

Tags: r, shiny, pivot-table, rcharts

I try to create shiny app with

`rpivotTable` and `nvd3 rcharts`

all works , but when i try to to show any chart from pivot 
i get error

> `An error occurred rendering the PivotTable results.`

But if i use only `rpivotTable` charts works in pivot and i think that there is problem when using `rpivotTable` and `nvd3 rcharts` in one shiny app.

## Example

UI

```
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)
library(rpivotTable)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  showOutput('plot1',lib = "nvd3"),
  rpivotTableOutput('pivot1', width = "100%", height = "500px"))  
)
```

Server

```
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)
library(rpivotTable)

df=data.frame(A=c(1:10),B=c(-10:-1),C=c("x",rep(c("x","y","z"),3)))
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$pivot1 <- renderRpivotTable({
    rpivotTable(data =df ,
                width="100%", height="500px")
  })

  output$plot1=renderChart2({
    myform <- as.formula(paste('A','~','B'))

    n2 <- nPlot(myform,  group ="C", data = df, type = 'multiBarChart')
    n2$chart(margin = list(left = 100))
    n2$chart(reduceXTicks = F)
    n2$set(width = 800, height = 500) 

    print(n2)
  })
  })
```

Give me [image]

If i use only `rpivotTable` charts in pivot works
[image]

When i look at inspect i see

```
TypeError: a.axisTimeFormat.multi is not a function
    at e.i.initParams (c3.min.js:1)
    at e.i.init (c3.min.js:1)
    at new d (c3.min.js:1)
    at Object.k.generate (c3.min.js:1)
    at Object.renderer (c3_renderers.coffee:129)
    at t.fn.pivot (pivot.coffee:546)
    at pivot.coffee:835
```

Is there way to fix it?

Package versions :

```
rpivotTable_0.1.5.7                    
rCharts_0.4.2    
shiny_0.12.2.9005
```

Thanks!

Comment: May be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23151171/rcharts-conflict-between-leaflet-and-nvd3-in-shiny

Comment: I know that problem some where in JavaScript but dont know how to fix it...( add error to question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this is due to the double loading of the `n3` libraries. To avoid this issue (this is more of a hack than a fix), you could plot the `rcharts` frame in an `iframe` to avoid `js` and `css` issues.

To do this, you can use `uiOutput`/`renderUI` for the shiny part, and `show` to output the `rCharts`.

Here's an example:

```
library(shiny)
library(rCharts)
library(rpivotTable)

df=data.frame(A=c(1:10),B=c(-10:-1),C=c("x",rep(c("x","y","z"),3)))

ui <-shinyUI(fluidPage(
        uiOutput('plot1'),
        rpivotTableOutput('pivot1')  
))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
        output$pivot1 <- renderRpivotTable({
                rpivotTable(data =df)
        })

        output$plot1=renderUI({
                myform <- as.formula(paste('A','~','B'))
                n2 <- nPlot(myform,  group ="C", data = df, type = 'multiBarChart')
                n2$chart(margin = list(left = 100))
                n2$chart(reduceXTicks = F)
                HTML(paste(capture.output(n2$show('iframesrc', cdn = TRUE)), collapse = '\n'))

        })
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: Thanks, I think its what i needed

Comment: @NicE solution is great and deserves its votes.  The root of the problem is in the two packages requiring different releases for same JS libraries. An alternative solution is to fork `rpivotTable` and change the version in `yaml` etc.